# GASのエラー解消について（構文エラー: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'each' 行: 13 ファイル: コード.gs）

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

[こちらのサイト](https://tonari-it.com/gas-chatwork-time-card/)を拝見して、そっくりそのまま使用したいと思い、スプレッドシートにスクリプトを入れて保存しようとしたところ、`構文エラー: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'each' 行: 13 ファイル: コード.gs`という表示が出ました。

調べてみたところ、どうやらfor構文が上手く行っていないようなのですが、どのように修正したらよいか教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

これまで進めた作業は以下のとおりです。

- スプレッドシートを用意し、勤怠管理シートを作成した
- HP内に記載されているスクリプトを勤怠管理スプレッドシートのAppsScriptに貼り付けた
- ChatworkからAPIを取得し、`headers : {"X-ChatWorkToken" : '---------------------'}`の`---------------------`部分に貼り付けた
- `var roomID = XXXXXXXX; //ルームID`の`XXXXXXXX`を実際のルームIDに変更した

以下がスクリプトです。

```
function recordTime(){
  var params = {
    headers : {"X-ChatWorkToken" : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'}, 
    method : "get"
  };
  var roomID = XXXXXX;
  var url = "https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/" + roomID + "/messages?force=0";
  try{
    var respons = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    var json = JSON.parse(respons.getContentText());
    for each (var obj in json){
      if(obj.body.match(/出勤/) || obj.body.match(/おはよう/)){
        Logger.log("出勤");
      }else if(obj.body.match(/退勤/) || obj.body.match(/お疲れ/)){
        Logger.log("退勤");
      }
    }
}catch(e){
    Logger.log('エラーが発生しました');
    Logger.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: 質問のコード部分を正しくコード入力された方が、まともに質問に対処してくれる人も増えるかと思いますよ

Comment: ありがとうございます。スクリプト部分が見づらくて回答しようがないですね、失礼しました。きれいに表示されるように編集してみます。

Comment: raccyさん、編集ありがとうございます。格段に見やすくなりました。

Comment: 実際に App Script 上でコードを入力すると分かりますが、`for each` という構文が現在はサポートされていないのではないでしょうか？ 参照している記事は 2016 年時点とかなり古い記述なのは注意が必要です。

Comment: for each構文は現在はサポートされていないんですね。ショックです・・・ありがとうございます。他の構文を使用しないといけないので、ちょっとこれはこれで調べてみようと思います。

Answer (score 0):

今の場合、次のような修正はいかがでしょうか。

```js
function recordTime() {
  var params = {
    headers: { "X-ChatWorkToken": 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX' },
    method: "get"
  };
  var roomID = "XXXXXX";
  var url = "https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/" + roomID + "/messages?force=0";
  try {
    var respons = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    var text = respons.getContentText();
    if (!text) {
      Logger.log("No new messages.");
      return;
    }
    var json = JSON.parse(text);
    json.forEach(obj => {
      if (obj.body.match(/出勤/) || obj.body.match(/おはよう/)) {
        Logger.log("出勤");
      } else if (obj.body.match(/退勤/) || obj.body.match(/お疲れ/)) {
        Logger.log("退勤");
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('エラーが発生しました');
    Logger.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

#### Note

注意点として、表示されているスクリプトでは`force=0`を使用されているようです。`force`のquery parameterは下記のような説明があります。[Ref](https://developer.chatwork.com/reference/get-rooms-room_id-messages)

> 強制的に最大件数まで取得するかどうか。0を指定した場合（既定）は前回取得分からの差分のみを返しますが、1を指定した場合は強制的に最新のメッセージを最大100件まで取得します。

そのため、スクリプトを実行した際、前回の取得後から新たにメッセージがない場合は、`respons.getContentText()`には値がないため、エラーが発生します。そこで、`if (!text) {,,,}`を追加しました。新たなメッセージがない場合は、`No new messages.`が表示されます。

#### Reference

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)